# How to send all request to index.html - reactjs

Tags: javascript, linux, reactjs

I'm using linux OS and apache.
I created a `webapp` directory inside `public_html`. inside `public_html` I have a landing page. I want to keep this landing page.
all resources can fetch as well.
but I got Page not found error. 
I found out that I should send all requests to `index.html` file.

.htaccess file:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>


  #######################################################################
  # GENERAL                                                             #
  #######################################################################

  # Make apache follow sym links to files
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  # If somebody opens a folder, hide all files from the resulting folder list
  IndexIgnore */*


  #######################################################################
  # REWRITING                                                           #
  #######################################################################

  # Enable rewriting
  RewriteEngine On

  # If its not HTTPS
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

  # Comment out the RewriteCond above, and uncomment the RewriteCond below if you're using a load balancer (e.g. CloudFlare) for SSL
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https

  # Redirect to the same URL with https://, ignoring all further rules if this one is in effect
  RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

  # If we get to here, it means we are on https://

  # If the file with the specified name in the browser doesn't exist
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # and the directory with the specified name in the browser doesn't exist
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  # and we are not opening the root already (otherwise we get a redirect loop)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\/$

  # Rewrite all requests to the root
  RewriteRule ^(.*) /

</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  # Do not cache sw.js, required for offline-first updates.
  <FilesMatch "sw\.js$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

but I got `not found` message error:

https://parsebar.com/webapp/login

Answer (score 1):

I use this snippet in my `.htaccess` when my react app runs in a subfolder:

```
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```